# How to implement squares grid design

Tags: html, css, sass

Is there a practical way to implement such a design in the attached image on a webpage using CSS, What only came to my head is creating a grid add and giving its items a border and placing the rest wherever... but that does really sound and feel ugly. Any ideas?

[image: squares grid design]

Comment: You can use CSS grid or flexbox for this design very easy if you do some research...

Comment: I think that CSS Grids will fit for such layout very well https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: sure, but for the all those empty squares, do I have to place empty divs all over the place?

Comment: No need for empty "div" this is what grid does, it creates an amount of rows and columns each element taking up a percentage of the row/column using the supported units within grid css. Check out the link @Kuzzy linked to, it will make sense if you study that article its a good one for grid layout.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem now. The comments so far seem to be about positioning the elements on the grid but I thought you were asking how to get those grid lines showing (without having to put empty elements in each otherwise empty grid cell) - is that right?

Comment: You could have a grid which will help you position each of the 'real' elements. But to get the grid lines I'd just use a couple of repeating linear-gradients as background image.

Comment: @AHaworth Yes, correct the positioning thing I know but I was asking for a cleaner way to do the lining thing without having to have empty divs

Comment: @dalelandry what about those lines, the point of the design is those lines that show as a grid, how to accomplish them without the empty divs with border.

Comment: @AHaworth do you know how? I'm really not getting the linear-gradients deal

Comment: The question is closed so I can't put up a proper answer but here's the basic idea. You can draw horizontal and vertical lines for example: 
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 0 49%, black 49% 51%, transparent 51% 100%), linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0 49%, black 49% 51%, transparent 51% 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: 100% calc(100% / 23), calc(100% / 15) 100%;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very basic example of grid using your layout.

**NOTE:** ***You may need to use some restrictions on resizing to get the layout to keep its aspect ratio.***

**Two important notes:**

1. In the grid container we use ***`grid-template-areas`*** and we literally write in the placement of each corresponding elements ***unique*** class into the layout. ***'dots'*** --> `.` will skip that section of the ***row/column***.
2. Each unique element will have a class assigned to it that will point to its self using the ***`grid-area`***:

```
.img-1 {
  grid-area: img-1;
}
```

In my example I created 21 rows with I think 16 columns. This can be expressed using `grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr` or `grid-template-rows: repeat(1fr)`, basically we are telling the grid to use up 1 fraction of the row for each element 100% of the row = 16 equal elements, then they are placed in the DOM relevant to their `grid-template-areas`.

A great way to 'get it' is to visually inspect the grid-template-areas with each line on a new line as I have laid it out in my example. You can see where the `img-1` takes up in regards to the other elements in the layout. Remember *dots* represent nothing, a single fraction of that row/column will get taken up with nothing in it.

Hope this helps.

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  width: 550px; /*for display purposes to keep aspect ratio*/
  height: 900px; /*for display purposes to keep aspect ratio*/
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas: 
  ". . . . . . . . . . . . . . ." 
  "img-1 img-1 img-1 img-1 img-1 img-1 . . . . . . . . ." 
  "img-1 img-1 img-1 img-1 img-1 img-1 . pr-2 pr-2 title-2 title-2 title-2 title-2 title-2 ." 
  "img-1 img-1 img-1 img-1 img-1 img-1 . . . title-2 title-2 title-2 title-2 title-2 ." 
  "img-1 img-1 img-1 img-1 img-1 img-1 . . . title-2 title-2 title-2 title-2 title-2 ." 
  "img-1 img-1 img-1 img-1 img-1 img-1 . . . img-2 img-2 img-2 img-2 img-2 img-2" "pr-1 pr-1 title-1 title-1 title-1 title-1 title-1 title-1 title-1 img-2 img-2 img-2 img-2 img-2 img-2" 
  ". . title-1 title-1 title-1 title-1 title-1 title-1 title-1 img-2 img-2 img-2 img-2 img-2 img-2" 
  ". . title-1 title-1 title-1 title-1 title-1 title-1 title-1 img-2 img-2 img-2 img-2 img-2 img-2" 
  "heading heading heading heading heading heading heading heading . img-2 img-2 img-2 img-2 img-2 img-2" 
  "heading heading heading heading heading heading heading heading . img-2 img-2 img-2 img-2 img-2 img-2" 
  "heading heading heading heading heading heading heading heading . pr-3 pr-3 line-3 line-3 line-3 line-3" "heading heading heading heading heading heading heading heading . pr-4 pr-4 line-4 line-4 line-4 line-4" 
  ". . . . . . . . img-6 img-6 img-6 img-6 img-6 img-6 img-6" 
  "pr-5 pr-5 title-5 title-5 title-5 title-5 title-5 title-5 img-6 img-6 img-6 img-6 img-6 img-6 img-6" 
  ". . title-5 title-5 title-5 title-5 title-5 title-5 img-6 img-6 img-6 img-6 img-6 img-6 img-6" 
  ". . title-5 title-5 title-5 title-5 title-5 title-5 img-6 img-6 img-6 img-6 img-6 img-6 img-6" 
  "img-5 img-5 img-5 img-5 img-5 img-5 img-5 . img-6 img-6 img-6 img-6 img-6 img-6 img-6" 
  "img-5 img-5 img-5 img-5 img-5 img-5 img-5 . img-6 img-6 img-6 img-6 img-6 img-6 img-6" 
  "img-5 img-5 img-5 img-5 img-5 img-5 img-5 . ico-1 ico-1 sec-1 line-5 line-5 line-5 line-5" 
  "img-5 img-5 img-5 img-5 img-5 img-5 img-5 . ico-1 ico-1 . . . . ." 
  "img-5 img-5 img-5 img-5 img-5 img-5 img-5 desc desc desc desc desc desc desc desc" 
  "img-5 img-5 img-5 img-5 img-5 img-5 img-5 desc desc desc desc desc desc desc desc";
}

.img-1 {
  grid-area: img-1;
}

.title-2 {
  grid-area: title-2;
}

.pr-2 {
  grid-area: pr-2;
}

.img-2 {
  grid-area: img-2;
}

.title-1 {
  grid-area: title-1;
}

.pr-1 {
  grid-area: pr-1;
}

.pr-3 {
  grid-area: pr-3;
}

.pr-4 {
  grid-area: pr-4;
}

.line-3 {
  grid-area: line-3;
}

.line-4 {
  grid-area: line-4;
}

.heading {
  grid-area: heading;
}

.pr-5 {
  grid-area: pr-5;
}

.img-6 {
  grid-area: img-6;
}

.title-5 {
  grid-area: title-5;
}

.img-5 {
  grid-area: img-5;
}

.ico-1 {
  grid-area: ico-1;
}

.sec-1 {
  grid-area: sec-1;
}

.line-5 {
  grid-area: line-5;
}

.desc {
  grid-area: desc;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}


.container * {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.container *:after {
  content: attr(class);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="section img-1"></div>
  <div class="section title-2"></div>
  <div class="section pr-2"></div>
  <div class="section img-2"></div>
  <div class="section title-1"></div>
  <div class="section pr-1"></div>
  <div class="section pr-3"></div>
  <div class="section pr-4"></div>
  <div class="section line-3"></div>
  <div class="section line-4"></div>
  <div class="section heading"></div>
  <div class="section pr-5"></div>
  <div class="section img-6"></div>
  <div class="section title-5"></div>
  <div class="section img-5"></div>
  <div class="section ico-1"></div>
  <div class="section sec-1"></div>
  <div class="section line-5"></div>
  <div class="section desc"></div>
</div>
```

Using Flex with calculated values using variables set with a division of your incremented boxes.

You simply set up rows and then move your elements around relative tot heir positions within the rows. It makes it easy with your set up as you have a set number of boxes which can be used using top and left positioning with calculated values of the percentage of the parent elements width/height. See the examples and study the CSS to see how it can be accomplished.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  --w-inc: calc(100%/15);
  --h-inc: calc(100%/23);
}

#cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 550px;
  height: 800px;
  background-image: url('https://webstockreview.net/images/square-border-png-6.png');
  background-size: var(--w-inc) var(--h-inc);
}

.box {
border: 1px solid #ddd;
background: white;
}

.row-1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(var(--h-inc) * 5);
  position: relative;
  top: var(--h-inc);
  display: flex;
}

.img-1 {
  width: calc(var(--w-inc) * 6);
  height: 100%;
}

.pr-2 {
  width: calc(var(--w-inc) * 2);
  height: 20%;
  position: relative;
  left: calc(var(--w-inc) * 1);
  top: 20%;
}

.title-2 {
  width: calc(var(--w-inc) * 5);
  height: 60%;
  position: relative;
  left: calc(var(--w-inc) * 1);
  top: 20%;
}

.row-2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(var(--h-inc) * 5);
  position: relative;
  top: var(--h-inc);
  display: flex;
}

.pr-1 { 
  width: calc(var(--w-inc) * 2);
  height: 20%;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.title-1 {
  width: calc(var(--w-inc) * 7);
  height: 60%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.img-2 {
  width: calc(var(--w-inc) * 6);
  height: 120%;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: -20%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.row-3 { 
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(var(--h-inc) * 2);
  position: relative;
  top: calc(var(--h-inc) * 1);
  display: flex;
}
.title-3 {
  width: calc(var(--w-inc) * 8);
  height: 200%;
  position: relative;
  top: -100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.rows {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}
.row-4 {
  height: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.pr-4 {
  width: calc(100% / 7 * 2);
  margin-left: calc(100% / 7);
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.title-4 {
  width: 100%;
}
.row-5 {
  height: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.pr-5 {
  width: calc(100% / 7 * 2);
  margin-left: calc(100% / 7);
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.title-5 {
  width: 100%;
}

.row-6 {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(var(--h-inc) * 6);
  position: relative;
  top: var(--h-inc);
  display: flex;
}

.pr-6 {
  width: calc(var(--w-inc) * 2);
  height: calc(100% / 6);
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: calc(100% / 6);
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.title-6 {
  width: calc(var(--w-inc) * 6);
  height: calc(100% / 6 * 3);
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: calc(100% / 6);
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.img-6 {
  width: calc(var(--w-inc) * 7);
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.rows-5 {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(var(--h-inc) * 4);
  position: relative;
  top: var(--h-inc);
  display: flex;
}

.img-7 {
  width: calc(var(--w-inc) * 7);
  height: 150%;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: calc(100% / 6 * -3);
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.rows-1 {
  height: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.icon-1 {
  width: calc(100% / 8 * 2);
  margin-left: calc(100% / 8);
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.sec-2 {
  width: calc(100% / 8);
  height:  calc(100% / 4 * 2);
}
.sec-3 {
  width: calc(100% / 8 * 4);
  height:  calc(100% / 4 * 2);
}
.rows-2 {
  height: 50%;
  width 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <div class="row-1">
    <div class="img-1 box">
    </div>
    <div class="pr-2 box">
    </div>
    <div class="title-2 box">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-2">
    <div class="pr-1 box">
    </div>
    <div class="title-1 box">
    </div>
    <div class="img-2 box">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-3">
    <div class="title-3 box"></div>
    <div class="rows">
      <div class="row-4">
        <div class="pr-4 box"></div>
        <div class="title-4 box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row-5">
        <div class="pr-5 box"></div>
        <div class="title-5 box"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-6">
    <div class="pr-6 box"></div>
    <div class="title-6 box"></div>
    <div class="img-6 box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="rows-5">
    <div class="img-7 box"></div>
    <div class="rows">
      <div class="rows-1">
        <div class="icon-1 box"></div>
        <div class="sec-2 box"></div>
        <div class="sec-3 box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="rows-2 box">
      </div>
    </div>
   
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the hard work! appreciate it. <3